# JQuery - click() function on link recognizes some links but not others

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I've modified this code to confirm opening a page when a link is clicked:

```
<a href="http://google.com" id="check">Visit Google!</a>

<script>
$('#check').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the href from redirecting directly
var linkURL = $(this).attr("href");
warnBeforeRedirect(linkURL);
});

function warnBeforeRedirect(linkURL) {
swal({
title: "このリンク開けますか?", 
text: "If you click 'OK', you will be redirected to " + linkURL, 
type: "warning",
showCancelButton: true
}, function() {
// Redirect the user
window.location.href = linkURL;
});
}
</script>
```

This code snipped works very well as it is embedded in my index.php page. However, another code snippet as seen here:

```
<a href='/classreg.php?studentid=<?php echo $row["studentid"]; ?>&classid=<?php echo $row["classID"]; ?>&furikae=2&class_time=<?php echo $datecheck; ?>' class="btn btn-warning" id="check">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right"></span>欠席 
</a>
```

doesn't work. The first link calls the function, whereas the second doesn't.

I assume something must be getting in the way of the id tag being recognized, but I'm not sure how to go about debugging this as I'm relatively new to JS and JQuery.

If I've forgotten to add any important information please let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `class` selector instead on the `id` selector. You cannot set same id's to the multiple elements. This is the problem that your first link works and others not.

so your code should looks like this

```
<a href="http://google.com" class="check" id="check">Visit Google!</a>
```

and the second href

```
<a href='/classreg.php?studentid=<?php echo $row["studentid"]; ?>&classid=<?php echo $row["classID"]; ?>&furikae=2&class_time=<?php echo $datecheck; ?>' class="btn btn-warning check" id="check1">
```

and in js use `$('.check')` instead of `$('#check')`

Comment: Thanks! That makes a lot of sense and now I feel foolish. How does the class selector work when I'm also using class for formatting with bootstrap? You'll notice my second link has class="btn btn-warning" Should it change to class="btn btn-warning check"?

Comment: Yea, you can set multiple classes to an elements.

Comment: @BenjaminJones In another hand you can just change the second to `id="check1"` and use selector `$('a[id^=check]')` instead of  `$('#check')` .. both ways will work with you

Comment: @SKJajoriya I set the class to 'class="btn btn-warning check"' but it's still not working on the second link, only the first.

Comment: Have you changed the selector in the click function ?

Comment: @SKJajoriya Got it working, had the link after the JQuery function! Thanks for the help!